# How do get the index of a table's column by using a structured reference in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a table with 3 columns. I want to write a formula that, given a structured reference, returns the index of the column. This will help me write VLookup formulas using the structured reference.

So, for example, for the table `MyTable` with columns `A`, `B`, `C` I'd like to be able to write:

```
=GetIndex(MyTable[C])
```

and have it return 3.

Right now I just make sure the table range starts on the sheet's first column and I write

```
=Column(MyTable[C])
```

but I want something a more robust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A suitable formula based on your example would be

```
=COLUMN(MyTable[C])-COLUMN(MyTable)+1
```

The first part of the forumla `COLUMN(MyTable[C])` will return the column number of the referenced column.

The second part of the formula *COLUMN(MyTable)* will always return the column number of the first column of the table.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another solution to the question you asked (or something close to it) is to use something like `=MATCH("C",MyTable[#Headers],0)`, which will return 3 in the example you posted.

However, if you used INDEX instead of VLOOKUP, you wouldn't need to do this.  For example, if you wanted to find the value of C in the row (assumingly there is no more than one) where A is equal to 2, you could use a formula like `=INDEX(MyTable[C],MATCH(2,MyTable[A],0))`, which is nicely self-documenting.

Comment: Even though I don't think the OP wanted this solution specifically, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I had that forehead slapping moment as soon as I saw "=MATCH("

Comment: Using the string literal `"C"` in this formula means that if you change the name of the C column in your referenced table this formula will break. Robert Mearns' answer is able to use `MyTable[C]` as the reference which will update as you rename the C column in the referenced table.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
Dim r As Range
MyLetter ="AA"
Set r = Range(MyLetter & "1")
MyIndex= r.Column
```

Edit re comment

```
Function GetRelativeColumn(Letter, RangeName)
Dim r As Range
Dim ColStart, ColRequired, ColTemp
Set r = Range(RangeName)

ColStart = r.Column
ColRequired = Range(Letter & "1").Column
ColTemp = ColRequired - ColStart + 1
If ColTemp < 1 Or ColTemp > r.Columns.Count Then
    MsgBox "Ooutside range"
Else
    GetRelativeColumn = ColTemp
End If
End Function
```

Comment: I think this is making 2 many assumptions. Basically I'd like a way to define a table "MyTable" which is any range. I then want to be able to get the index of a named column relative to the first column in "MyTable" can this function do that? Remember I'm using structured references. Either way ty

Answer (score 1):

=slight modification to eJames' respones:
=COLUMN(MyTable[ * ]) - MIN(COLUMN(MyTable)) + 1, where * is the column you want the index of.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: `=COLUMN(MyTable[*]) - COLUMN(MyTable[A]) + 1`, where `*` is the column whose index you want.

Comment: Is there a way to get the first column in a table? I don't rather not be locked into having "A" always be at the first index. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is your end goal? You may be better off using SUMIF (as I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098205/how-to-create-running-total-using-excel-table-structured-references/7098262#7098262)) or INDEX (as I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880168/excel-structured-reference-table-syntax/7098041)) to access your values rather than jumping back to row/column...