# Excel VBA changing my formulas in a table?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, listobject

Has anyone come across a situation where Excel seems to manipulate your formulas.
I have a sheet where I have an Index value in Column A. The First row starts with any non zero Value. Subsequent rows in the column increment the value. Eg

```
A1 = 1000
A2= A1+ 1
A3= A2 + 1
```

and so on/
I have another column B whose values will either be blank or a formula pointing to column A(usually the subsequent rows)
Eg:

```
B1.Formula = "=A2"
B2.Formula = "=A3"
B3.Value = ""
B4.value = "=A6"
```

Now I have a backup-restore functionality that lets me write out the data/formulas to a text file and then read it back in another workbook.
In the case of columns A and B, I am checking if the text value starts with "=" and then set either the value or formula of that cell depending on whether there is a formula or not.

So far the functionality has worked fine. It lets me restore accurately.

Now, if I convert this data range to a table and modify the code accordingly the behaviour is strange. I am using the ListObject structure to refer to the table. So for Column B my restore code is:

```
 If Left(soureString) = "=" Then
               'This is a formula
               Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Next").DataBodyRange(row).Formula = sourcestring
Else
               'This is a value
                Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Next").DataBodyRange(row).Value = soureString
End If
```

once I am done writing a row, I loop to the start and

```
Dim newRow AS listrow
Set newRow = Sheets("MySheet").Listrows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=False)
row = newRow.Index
```

But this time when I run the process. this is what I get:

```
B1.Formula = "=A5"
B2.Formula = "=A5"
B3.Value = ""
B4.value = "=A5"
```

Why are my formula values all changing to the same value when I use a table instead of a range?

Comment: Just to clarify: shouldn't `Sheets("MySheet").ListColumns("Next")` rather be  `Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Next")`?

Comment: This article [Formulas and Structured Data in Excel Tables](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/04/formulas-and-structured-data-in-excel-tables/) says "The great thing about converting to a Table is that when I add more data to the table, the formula is automatically copied down for me.

If I change this formula, then Excel will automatically copy the change to all rows in the column. And it doesn’t matter if I change the first cell at the top of the column or change a cell in the middle, all rows in the column will be modified." I'm not sure how to change this behavior though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when populating a ListObject (Table) from an Excel Add-in, setting `AutoFillFormulasInLists` was the solution.

My workaround is to save the current setting, set `AutoFillFormulasInLists` to false, populate the table with data, formulas etc, then set `AutoFillFormulasInLists` back to the original setting.

```
bool OriginalAutoFillFormulaInListsFlag = app.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists;
app.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = false;

//[ListObject population code....]

if (OriginalAutoFillFormulaInListsFlag == true)
{
    app.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = true;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.  Ideally you could tell excel to stop doing this but I haven't been able to figure out how.  Supposedly doing the following is supposed to keep excel from copying the formulas:

`xlApp.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = false`

but it didn't work for me.

Using the answer from this question [How to create running total using Excel table structured references?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098262/155268) helped me.  It doesn't feel like the ideal solution but it does do the job.

I used this formula where `Weight` is a column name from my table.  `#This Row` is a "Special item specifier" and has a special meaning.  The syntax looks a little funky because it's what's called a [Structured Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx):

`=AVERAGE(INDEX([Weight],1):[[#This Row],[Weight]])`

The `INDEX([Weight],1)` part gives the reference for the 1st row in the Weight column

While the `[[#This Row],[Weight]]` part gives the reference for the current row in the Weight column.

So for example, if Weight is column J, and the current row is, say, 7 then this is equivalent to

`=AVERAGE(J1:J7)`

and on the 8th row it will be equivalent to

`=AVERAGE(J1:J8)` and so on

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the only way to solve the problem of formulas changing in Excel Tables when you insert in VBA is to insert at the **first row of the table**, NOT the bottom or the middle.  You can sort after.

And I always select or reference the `EntireRow` to do my insert in the Worksheet object not in the table itself.  I always put a table in its own  Worksheet anyway using `xx.Entirerow.Insert`.